# Ignoring sub-directories in .ackrc

Tags: ack

I'd like to get my .ackrc configured so ack doesn't look inside my test/coverage folder. So far I've ended up with this :

`--ignore-dir=coverage`

This works, but it doesn't feel quite as right as :

`--ignore-dir=test/coverage`

Problem is the latter doesn't work and test/coverage content is searched.

Am I missing something or is ack not prepared to deal with subdirectories ?

Comment: You're not missing anything. I'm looking as well but it doesn't seem to be an option as best I can tell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [ack changelog](http://betterthangrep.com/Changes) explicity mentions this as a feature,  supported since ack 1.93_02.
Quote: "The --ignore-dir option now can ignore entire paths relative to your current directory."

I tried it and it works. I would check if your test/coverage directory is directly relative to the folder you're running ack from. Otherwise I'm not sure what could be going on.

Comment: Good to know, ubuntu's ack version being 1.92 it didn't work for me. Hope they upgrade soon. Thanks.

Comment: the link simply redirects to home page.. m having the same problem.. but not getting the exact solution. what should i write in .ackrc.